# How can I set Typescript type to be string or HTML element?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How can I set Typescript type to be string or HTML element? Should be simple, but currently can't seem to find any answer to it.

Basically I want to give "title" props a string or HTML.

```
   <Dialog
     title={<div>some HTML</div>}
   </Dialog>

   <Dialog
      title={"Some string"}
   </Dialog>

   export type DialogProps = {
     title?: Element | string | undefined;
   };
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nr2Q3N), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the type `React.ReactNode`.  This includes `JSX.Element` as well as `string`, `number`, `undefined`, etc.

Here's the relevant block of the [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9741d1aa69762f3f28da3cc99842afcd3065b461/types/react/index.d.ts#L228):

```
type ReactText = string | number;
type ReactChild = ReactElement | ReactText;
interface ReactNodeArray extends Array<ReactNode> {}
type ReactFragment = {} | ReactNodeArray;
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

---

**Ambiguous `Element`**

If you just use the type `Element` with no prefix then you get the definition from `lib.dom.ts`.  The `JSX` namespace included with React has its own definition for `JSX.Element`.

The `<div>some HTML</div>` in your example is a `JSX.Element` and is actually not assignable to the `Element` type.

```
function requiresElement(el: Element) {}

requiresElement(<div>some HTML</div>); // error
```

> Argument of type 'JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.
>
> Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': attributes, classList, className, clientHeight, and 123 more.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mMyzlm)

Comment: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type '(string & (boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | null)) | undefined'.
  Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string & ReactPortal'.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: Where is the `Element` coming from?  Are you passing some variable that has type `Element`?  https://tsplay.dev/N7b3qw

Comment: In your original types the problem that you were having was due to two different definitions of `Element`.  You are requiring a DOM `Element` but `<div>some HTML</div>` creates a `JSX.Element`.

Comment: If for some reason you need to accept a DOM `Element` then `title?: React.ReactNode | Element` seems ok.  But it seems unlikely that you have an `Element`.  Also I'm not sure why you have `string &` in your error since we are dealing with an `or` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You could set your props type as interface:

```
interface DialogProps {
   title: JSX.Element | string
}

interface State {}

class Dialog extends React.Component<DialogProps, State> {
  ...
}
```